# Airflow ECS Register Task Operator, error when passing env. variables

Tags: airflow, boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

when I am trying to pass env. variables to my ECSRegisterTaskOperator, I get the following error:

Unknown parameter in input: "environment", must be one of: family, taskRoleArn, executionRoleArn, networkMode, containerDefinitions, volumes, placementConstraints, requiresCompatibilities, cpu, memory, tags, pidMode, ipcMode

However according to the documentation for boto3 with Ecs, one has to pass env variables via the environment dictionary.
[reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.register_task_definition ]

The part of my task looks like this:

```
register_task_kwargs={
"cpu": "256",
"memory": "512",
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"environment": [
{
"name": "REDSHIFT_HOST",
"value": redshift_cluster_test_connection.host
},
{
"name": "REDSHIFT_USER",
"value": "redshift_cluster_test_connection.user"
},
{ "name": "REDSHIFT_PW",
"value": redshift_cluster_test_connection.password}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `environment` settings go inside the `containerDefinitions`. You have them at the top level, instead of inside the `containerDefinitions`.

Comment: thanks a lot that helped. I now get the error: AWS Connection (conn_id='aws-fargate', conn_type='aws') credentials retrieved from login and password.
INFO - No connection ID provided. Fallback on boto3 credential strategy (region_name=None) botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.                                   I tried solving it but so far nothing worked, I have specified a connection_id and also a region inside the connection section in airflows web ui.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Airflow so I can't help you there. I suggest posting that as a new question on this site.